# Creating MvxTableViewCell without nib

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I want to make MvxTableViewCell without nib file, but I search in stackoverflow, github
and google, I couldn't good sample to make MvxTableViewCell manually.

I tried such code,

```
namespace KittenView.Touch
{
    public partial class KittenCell : MvxTableViewCell
    {
        public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString ("KittenCell");

        private readonly MvxImageViewLoader _imageViewLoader;
        MonoTouch.UIKit.UIImageView MainImage { get; set; }
        MonoTouch.UIKit.UILabel NameLabel { get; set; }
        MonoTouch.UIKit.UILabel PriceLabel { get; set; }

        public KittenCell () : base ()
        {
            this.Frame = new RectangleF(0f,0f,100f,120f);
            MainImage = new UIImageView (new RectangleF(0f,0f,100f,100f));
            NameLabel = new UILabel (new RectangleF (0f, 80f, 100f, 20f));
            PriceLabel = new UILabel (new RectangleF (0f, 100f, 100f, 20f));
            Add (MainImage);
            Add (NameLabel);
            Add (PriceLabel);

            _imageViewLoader = new MvxImageViewLoader(() => this.MainImage);

            this.DelayBind (() => {
                var set = this.CreateBindingSet<KittenCell, Kitten>();
                set.Bind(NameLabel).To (kitten => kitten.Name);
                set.Bind(PriceLabel).To(kitten => kitten.Price);
                set.Bind(_imageViewLoader).To (kitten => kitten.ImageUrl);
                set.Apply ();
            });

            this.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation ((float)Math.PI / 2.0f);
        }

        public static KittenCell Create ()
        {
            return new KittenCell ();
        }
    }
}
```

But this code occurs Exception in execution phase, said

SetValue:forUndefinedKey:]this calss in not key value coding-compliant for key MainImage.

at AppDelegate.cs's window.MakeKeyAndVisible().

How do I use MvxTableViewCell without nib?

Regards,

Ko-hei

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use `RegisterClassForCell` to register your cell with the table view and `DequeueReusableCell` to then later create or reuse cells.

In order to allow UIKit to create instances of this class using this method inside the dequeue calls, then I think you need to add;

- a `[Register("KittenCell")]` attribute in front of the class - this attribute is used by MonoTouch to tell the ObjectiveC runtime about this managed class - it allows instances of this managed class to be created from ObjectiveC,
- a constructor which takes an `(IntPtr handle)` parameter which it passes down to the `base(handle)` constructor. This constructor is used to allow the managed C# object to be created alongside the underlying unmanaged UIKit object.

If you add those 2 items, I believe your celll will get created. Further, if you switch to the simpler `RegisterClassForCell` API, then I think you can remove the parameterless constructor and the static `Create` method.

Comment: Thank you @Stuart , I change cell class and add `TableView.RegisterClassForCellReuse (typeof(KittenCell), new NSString("KittenCell"));` to TableViewController it looks working. But sorry, I forgot that SubView in Cell must not to add View but to add ContentView, so I change `Add(MainImage);` to `COntentView,Add(MainImage)`. Then it raise errors, because of ContentView is null in Constructor. Where should I add subview in MvxTableViewCell?

Comment: Sorry, I found this page
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6176/why-is-contentview-null-when-using-mvvmcross-mvxtablecellview
So I initialize cell in separate method, works fine.
Thank you!